# Where is the normative rule that restricts what the declaration can be in a explicit specialization?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

On the grammar of explicit specialization

> explicit-specialization:
>
> > template < > *declaration*
>
> declaration:
>
> > - block-declaration
> > - nodeclspec-function-declaration
> > - ...
> > - explicit-instantiation
> > - ...

The *declaration* could be anything that is a valid declaration on its grammar. Consider this example

```cpp
template<class T>
struct A{
  template<class Y>
  struct B{};
};

template<>
template struct A<int>::B<int>;  //declaration: explicit-instantiation
```

Both GCC and Clang cannot recognize the [syntax](https://godbolt.org/z/6saeG7xso). Where is the rule that restricts the *declaration* cannot be an explicit instantiation?

Comment: In your explicit specialization of `A`, there is no indication it is supposed to have an inner `B`.

Comment: @cigien It is a *declaration*, as per [dcl.dcl#dcl.pre-1], `declaration: explicit-instantiation`. Your link cannot be openned.

Comment: @jxh `A<int>` is a specialization that results in the implicit instantiation of that specialization. `template<> template<> struct A<int>::B<int>{};` is valid.

Comment: Maybe I'm slow today, but shouldn't the declaration be `template<>
template <> struct A<int>::B<int>;` ?   (note the extra `<>` pair after the second usage of `template` keyword).

Comment: @Peter I didn't talk about the explicit specialization of `B<int>`. I'm talking about what the *declaration* can be in an explicit-specialization. Note, the second line is an **explicit instantiation**.

Comment: @xmh0511: Ok, but that is not what your code is trying to compile. What happens when you add the extra `<>` in that is not in your post?

Comment: @jxh I just said `B<int>` is an inner member of `A<int>`.

Comment: @xmh0511 `template<> template <> struct A<int>::B<int>; ` was in your comment. But your code in your post is `template<>
template struct A<int>::B<int>;`

Comment: @jxh That is just for *In your explicit specialization of A, there is no indication it is supposed to have an inner B*

Comment: @xmh0511 I admit to being a bit confused. You expect two different syntax to have the same semantics?

Comment: @jxh Nope, I just said the implicit instantiation of `A<int>` will implicitly instantiate its nested class template, which is used to counter your first comment.

Comment: Right, my first comment was how I interpreted the intent of the code, which is to specialize `A<int>`.

Comment: @jxh The sole declaration `template struct A<int>::B<int>;` itself is a valid declaration. Since the definition of class template `B` is reachable from this point as per [temp.explicit#5]. Of course, this issue does not intend to discuss this problem. I'm looking for the restrictions on the *declaration* of an explicit-specialization.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, the grammar for an explicit specialization requires a *declaration* after `template<>`. However, just because some syntax satisfies the grammar production rules, it's not necessarily valid code.

In the case of explicit specializations, the entities that can be explicitly specialized with this syntax are listed in [temp.expl.spec#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#1)

> An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>
> > (1.1) function template
> >
> > (1.2) class template
> >
> > ...
>
> can be declared by a declaration introduced by `template<>` ...

The syntax `template struct A<int>::B<int>;` is an explicit instantiation, which is not listed here, since it's not an entity that can be explicitly specialized.

Comment: I don't think `template<> struct A<int>::B<int>` is a class template. How would it be accepted?

Comment: @xmh0511 It's a member class template, and it can be specialized as per http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#15

Comment: `template<> struct A<int>::B<int>` itself is not a member class template, it's an explicit specialization of that member class template. Analogy, `template struct A<int>::B<int>` is an explicit instantiation of that member class template.

Comment: I also think that list just talks about which entities can be explicitly specialized, it does not restrict how the approach is.

Comment: @xmh0511 I don't think I fully understand your question. You seem to be asking why the code you've shown is not valid, and my answer shows how it's not covered by any of the cases for explicit specializations. I feel I should stress that just because some syntax is allowed by the grammar doesn't mean that the syntax is valid.

Comment: I'm expecting some rules in [temp.expl.spec] that is just similar to [temp#pre-2] that designates what the declaration can be.  Again, the quote you cited here is just about which entities can be explicit specialization, it didn't restrict what the *declaration* should be. The clue is *can be declared by **a declaration***

Comment: *I feel I should stress that just because some syntax is allowed by the grammar doesn't mean that the syntax is valid.*, of course, so I'm looking for the rule that restricts what the declaration should be. However, the rule you cited is not sufficient to interpret this issue since I didn't ask which entities can be explicitly specialized.